# How to re-assign `sys.excepthook` once for the whole package?

Tags: python, exception

If I write `sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions` in `__main__` and an unhandled exception occurs in:

- `__main__`, the new exception handler is used.
- one of the imported modules, the new exception handler is **not** used.

I can add the following to every module where I want the new exception handler to be used:

```
import sys
from my_funcs import log_uncaught_exceptions
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
```

... but I feel it could be done in a cleaner way, plus I don't want to modify 3rd-party dependencies I'm using.

Making a module out of the above code and importing it did not re-assign the new exception handler for that module.

**Question:** What is a clean way to re-assign the exception handler for the entire package?

Answer (score 2):

with main.py as this:

```
import sys

def except1(type,value,traceback):
    print 'except1'

if __name__=='__main__':
    sys.excepthook=except1

import foo
```

and foo.py as this:

```
raise Exception("foo exception")
```

I get

```
$ python main.py
except1
```

which is what I expect.  Did you assign sys.excepthook before any "import" statements?

Comment: Ahh, what I was encountering was this: any exception that occurs in threading.Thread is *caught* by this Thread class; it catches the exception and prints the stacktrace. What this means is that if it catches the exception it's not an unhandled exception (i.e. the exception doesn't go "all the way up out of the stack"), and hence not handled by `sys.excepthook`. Thanks for the help anyway.